# Fetching data in React's useEffect() returns data “undefined”

Tags: reactjs, api

I am trying to fetch data in reactjs with help of use effect hook but after accessing that in return div it is showing data undefined code is given below for that

```
import React,{ useEffect } from 'react'

export default function Home() {
useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://lighthouse-dot-webdotdevsite.appspot.com//lh/newaudit", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
      "url": "https://piyushsthr.netlify.app",
      "replace": true,
      "save": false
    }),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
      },
      credentials: "same-origin"
    })
     .then(res => res.json()) // this is the line you need
     .then(function(data) {
  
  
      console.log(data.lhrSlim[0].score)
      //return data;
  
    }).catch(function(error) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-expressions
      error.message
    })
  }, )
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{data.lhrSlim[0].score}</h1>
    </div>
  )
}
```

can anyone help me to fix this thing

Comment: seems to be working https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-surf-v9gjb?file=/src/App.js

Comment: You're not storing the data of the fetch function anywhere, that's why it shows undefined. You should store the data in the state after processing it and iterating on the JSX.

Comment: i am trying to access that thing in UI see like this       <h1>{data.lhrSlim[0].score}</h1>

Comment: for that you have to save the data in state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly show the content of the request directly on the UI, to do that either it has to be a prop or be stored in the state, for example you could do this.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

export default function Home() {
const [State, setState] = useState("");

useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://lighthouse-dot-webdotdevsite.appspot.com//lh/newaudit", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
      "url": "https://piyushsthr.netlify.app",
      "replace": true,
      "save": false
    }),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
      },
      credentials: "same-origin"
    })
     .then(res => res.json()) // this is the line you need
     .then(function(data) {
  
      setState(data.lhrSlim[0].score);

    }).catch(function(error) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-expressions
      error.message
    })
  }, )
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{State}</h1>
    </div>
  )
}
```

That way you will be able to store the data from the response directly on the state of the component and be able to show it afterwards.

Comment: and if i need multiple data from that response then how i can do that like SEO and many more things so for that i need multiple states ?

Comment: You could create a object in the state and store all the necessary values there

Comment: i tried this thing const [State, setState] = useState([
  {
score:  data.lhrSlim[0].score,
  },
  {
    SEO:data.lhrSlim[1].seo,
  },
  ],);
but showing  undefined can you help me with that

Comment: You need to loop over the state now

Answer (score 1):

To display the data from the api add a state in your component.

```
const [score, setScore] = useState([]);
```

then set score

```
 .then(function (data) {
    setScore(data?.lhrSlim[0]?.score);
  })
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-surf-v9gjb?file=/src/App.js